# Linux install Tor Browser to USB?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I am using linuxmint, trying to run Tor browser from removable usb drive, don't want to leave it on HDD.
Tried to unpack Tor browser to USB, but it wont work.
'start-tor-browser.desktop' is set to home folder on HDD. 
is it enough to change path in that file?
I am new to linux, appreciate some help. Did someone tried this?
Will it leave any trace on that machine?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the `start-tor-browser.desktop` (the one in `tor-browser_$LANG/`) it should execute itself based on the position that it is being run from and shouldn't need editing:

`Exec=sh -c '"$(dirname "$*")"/Browser/start-tor-browser --detach || ([ ! -x "$(dirname "$*")"/Browser/start-tor-browser ] && "$(dirname "$*")"/start-tor-browser --detach)' dummy %k`

You can just directly execute the `start-tor-browser` shell script and it should run fine, e.g. by running from a terminal:

`/media/user/myusb/tor-browser_$LANG/Browser/start-tor-browser --detach`

This should work for pretty much any directory, and it should contain itself to itself, this is that it will only affect things within its own folder.

However a strong note if you've strong requirements for anti-forensic properties is that the host operating system may swap out chunks of memory to disk (`swap` or `pagefile.sys`) or the entire contents of memory to disk (`hibernation`). This would necessarily include the contents of your browsing session and might violate any anti-forensic expectation you may have. If you have a strong requirement to run Tor Browser on Linux based system with anti-forensic properties, you should consider instead using the USB for use of the [Tails](https://tails.boum.org/) operating system.

Comment: Thanks, in this case path was allready set to home dir, so I edited path to usb and started, got this
"The application launcher "start-tor-browser.desktop" has not been marked as trusted. If you do not know the source of this file, launching it may be unsafe."
When I click "Launch anyway", nothing happens...

Comment: I've no idea what all that "marked as trusted" stuff is about, something in your DE. Running the bash script from a terminal will work.

Comment: I think I fixed it, it works now. I edited that config file and changed path. Thanks for info about swap etc. I am trying to use Whonix, I like idea of isolation. I think Whonix dont use swap?

Comment: You are running "Whonix" as a VM. If the OS you are using Whonix on has swap, it will swap out Whonix's memory to disk, hibernate, etc. It doesn't matter what's run inside the VM.